# ASP.Net HttpContext IsAuthenticated Bug

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a problem with this code:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

It shows false, although when user is authenticated.

This process starts in Page_Load.
Value doesnt change until i execute this code:

```
Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenied.aspx");
```

Then its value gets true.

What is the problem?

Comment: What type of authentication do you use, is it forms/windows/password? Above code is not enough for others to find the problem. Consider post more details from your code.

Comment: its windows. Its just that code. it ask for authentification, if not Reidrects to the standard page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

to web.config. requests will be authenticated

Comment: Thanks for your help. It did work! Cant upvote, im sorry.